# How to scale a sprite with its center as origin?

Tags: xna, sprites, scale

I'm trying to zoom-in a sprite gradually from 0% to 100% (a sprite called SelectionBox), so it zooms from the middle of the sprite, not from the upper-left corner. I'm almost there, but I'm having problems with the sprite origin - it's not positioning it in the spot I told it to.

What's wrong with this code?

```
SpritePosition_FirstBox = New Vector2(15, 50)
MiddleOrigin = New Vector2(CSng(Texture_SelectionBox.Width / 2), CSng(Texture_SelectionBox.Height / 2))

spriteBatch.Draw(Texture_SelectionBox, SpritePosition_FirstBox, Nothing, Color.White, 0, MiddleOrigin, ScaleValue, SpriteEffects.None, 0.94)
```

Comment: What parameters does the draw function take?

Comment: @Polar [You can see here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433989.aspx). Is it still zooming towards the center or somewhere else? Are your `Battle.Texture_SelectionBox` size properties set to what you expect?

Comment: @Mikec Right now, it's 'stretching' the image from the top-left and it keeps getting bigger until it reaches the sprite's original size (which is not very big) - via the ScaleValue variable. I want it to 'stretch' or 'zoom' (keep getting bigger) from the center, not from the top-left. Battle.Texture_SelectionBox is already at the size I expect.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks, I didn't realise it was a standard XNA function (or that this question was about XNA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was missing:

Instead of

```
SpritePosition_FirstBox = New Vector2(15, 50)
```

It should be

```
SpritePosition_FirstBox = New Vector2(CSng(15 + (Texture_SelectionBox.Width / 2)), CSng(50 + (Texture_SelectionBox.Height / 2)))
```

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with where you're placing the origin relative to the scale factor. Take this for example:

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, // Texture
    new Vector2(0, 0),      // Position
    Nothing,                // Source rectangle
    Color.White,            // Color
    0,                      // Rotation
    new Vector2(5, 5),      // Origin
    new Vector2(0.5, 0.5),  // Scale
    SpriteEffects.None,     // Mirroring effect
    0.94);                  // Depth
```

Here we're drawing at position `0,0` from origin point `5,5` with a scale factor of `0.5, 0.5`, right? And in the following:

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, // Texture
    new Vector2(0, 0),      // Position
    Nothing,                // Source rectangle
    Color.White,            // Color
    0,                      // Rotation
    new Vector2(5, 5),      // Origin
    new Vector2(1, 1),      // Scale
    SpriteEffects.None,     // Mirroring effect
    0.94);                  // Depth
```

We're now drawing at a scale factor of `1,1` *but we're still drawing from the same origin.* So instead, you should try something like this:

```
Vector2 scaleFactor = new Vector2(0.5, 0.5);
Vector2 origin = new Vector2(myTexture.Width / 2 * scaleFactor.X, myTexture.Height / 2 * scaleFactor.Y);
SpriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, // Texture
    new Vector2(0, 0),      // Position
    Nothing,                // Source rectangle
    Color.White,            // Color
    0,                      // Rotation
    origin,                 // Origin
    scaleFactor,            // Scale
    SpriteEffects.None,     // Mirroring effect
    0.94);                  // Depth
```

That way you're expanding from the center of the texture relative to it's current size.